# How do I add a register in windows via .bat or .reg file in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT for web apps to acesss it?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, regedit

Context: We have some third party desktop applications installed on our users machine, and we would like to open them through our web applications links. I know how to create a **URL Protocol** manually, but we need a script to run that on demand.

Code I've tried:

```
set url=myapp://test

set app_file=C:\app_path\app.exe

reg add HKCR\%url%\shell\open\command /ve /t REG_SZ /d "\"%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe\" \"%1\"" /f

assoc .myapp="%url%" ftype %url%="%app_file%"
```

That was the result I got:

[image: Actual result]

The wanted result should be like this:

[image: Wanted result]

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to create the right registry structure on one computer, then export it to a `.reg` file that you can use on the other computers?

Comment: I was about to type the same thing as @harrrymc . Even if you pull this off from a batch file, get your registry right and pull in the batch file later (if you must).  A `.reg` file would probably be a much better option than this.  Even an [.inf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/about-inf-files) (not device driver) file could do the trick.. but that is a lost art even though it is supported.

Comment: @harrymc great idea. It worked for me. One more question. Is there a way that I can map multiple `.exe` files in a single URL protocol? Like `myapp://admin` and `myapp://profile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be simpler to create the right registry structure on one
computer, then export it to a `.reg` file that you can use on the
other computers.

You may also create one `.reg` file out of multiple files by simply
concatenating them in one text file.
Ensure a blank line as separator and remove duplicate
`Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00` lines.

If you wish to convert the `.reg` files to `.bat`, you could use the free
[Reg Converter](https://www.sordum.org/8478/reg-converter-v1-2/).